# Get all links containing "/product/"

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I would like to get all links that contain `/product/`. There are 17 links that contain `/product/`. How to do that?

There seem to be something wrong with this line

```
Dim srcs = From iframeNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                       Select iframeNode.Attributes("href").Value
```

How to add parameter to filter by `/product/`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim mainUrl As String = "https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/"
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(mainUrl)

        Dim srcs = From iframeNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                   Select iframeNode.Attributes("href").Value

        'print all the src you got
        For Each src In srcs
            Console.WriteLine(src)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

---

**EDIT:**

Working solution:

```
    Imports HtmlAgilityPack

    Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim mainUrl As String = "https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/"
            Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(mainUrl) '< - - - Load the webage into htmldocument

            Dim srcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='products-list-page']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
            For Each src As HtmlNode In srcs
                Console.WriteLine(src.Attributes("href").Value) '< - - - Print urls

            Next

                Console.Read()

        End Sub

    End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the webpage first, then select the nodes you want and attributes to print.

Here is one way:

```
    Dim mainUrl As String = "https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/"
    Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(mainUrl) '< - - - Load the webage into htmldocument

    Dim srcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='products-list-page']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
    For Each src As HtmlNode In srcs
        Console.WriteLine(src.Attributes("href").Value) '< - - - Print urls
    Next
```

You need to learn to debug, if you had inspected code you would have seen that you were setting the "htmlDoc" html to the url string instead of loading the actual webpage html.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have added `Console.Read()` after `Console.WriteLine` and as a result I see only one link. The first one. There is a loop, but why it is not working?

Comment: You will need to specify where is the error more, as this works fine for me, edit your question.

Comment: After running the code I am getting "https://www.nordicwater.com/product/mrs-meva-multi-rake-screen/" as a result in Console

Comment: Post all of your code that you have now, then well see. Guessing like this serves no purpose.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have added `Console.Read()` inside the loop *damn*